# Differences between Silverlight 2.0 and 3.0

Tags: silverlight, comparison

I am migrating a graphics intensive Silverlight application from 2.0 to 3.0 and at the same time evaluating if there are new features in Silverlight it could expose. What features would you suggest are the most important new ones in Silverlight 3.0?

I have gone over the [Silverlight Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Silverlight#Silverlight_3) which suggested the following are the most important new features in 3.0:

- New controls
- New audio and video decoding (AAC and H.246)
- Perspective 3D
- Element-to-element binding
- Limited filesystem access
- Installation for offline usage

What other changes / new features are notable as an application developer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a pretty good, fairly comprehensive summary of the new features here:

http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/03/18/silverlight-3-whats-new-a-guide.aspx

Answer (score 1):

WriteableBitmap is one of the most notable 3.0 features if you're working with images.